# Q:Total counts and pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pagination, controller

How can we add total search results counts and pagination in codeigniter.

i want to show total search results counts on result page with pagination. thanks
can anyone help

tried a lot but could'nt acheive.

please help

Model

```
function search_results($title, $params = array()){
            $this->db->select("ID,section,Title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,'movies/' AS dept,STATUS");
            $this->db->from('movies');
            $this->db->Like('Title',$title,'after');
            $this->db->or_Like('year',$title,'after');
            $this->db->or_Like('section',$title,'after');
            $query[] = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

            $this->db->select("ID,section,Title,img,year,lastupdateon AS ondate,'view/kid/' AS dept,STATUS");
            $this->db->from('kids');
            $this->db->Like('Title',$title,'after');
            $query[] = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

            $this->db->select("ID,views,Title,img,version AS year,ondate,'view/software/' AS dept,STATUS");
            $this->db->from('soft');
            $this->db->Like('Title',$title,'after');
            $query[] = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

            $this->db->select("ID,section,Title,img,'PC Game' AS year,ondate,'view/game/' AS dept,STATUS");
            $this->db->from('games');
            $this->db->Like('Title',$title,'after');
            $query[] = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

            $this->db->select("ID,season,Title,img,type AS year,lastupdatedon AS ondate,'view/tvshow/' AS dept,STATUS");
            $this->db->from('tvshows');
            $this->db->Like('Title',$title,'after');
            $query[] = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

            $union_query = join(' UNION ALL ',$query); // I use UNION ALL
            $union_query .= " ORDER BY ondate DESC"; 

            if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'count'){ 
            $result = $this->$union_query->num_rows();
            }

            $query = $this->db->query($union_query);
            //echo $query->num_rows();
            return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
function search(){
        $title=$this->input->get('Title');
        $data['data']=$this->blog_model->search_results($title);
        $config['per_page']= 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/index.php/tutorial/search').'/'; 
        $this->data['per_page_display'] = $config['per_page'];
        $conditions['returnType'] = 'count'; 
        $totalRec = $this->blog_model->search_results($conditions); 
        $config['total_rows'] = count($conditions);
        $this->data['totalcount'] = $config['total_rows'];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['per_page'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $this->data['page'] = $offset;
        $this->load->view('search_view',$data);
    }
```

Comment: you have already done code in the model `if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'count'){ 
            $result = $this->$union_query->num_rows();
            }` just need to pass relevent params.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: In the controller, to get the total you have to pass the first param as title after that the condition

```
$totalRec = $this->blog_model->search_results($title, $conditions);
```

Problem 2: In the model, last db should like below

```
$query = $this->db->query($union_query)->get();
if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'count') 
{
    return $query->num_rows();
}

return $query->result();
```

Note that I don't understand the logic behind the pagination, But you can access the model function one time to get the data and count like below

Controller:

```
$result = $this->blog_model->search_results($title);
$data['data'] = $result['data'];
$data['totalcount'] = $result['total'];
```

Model:

```
$data = [];
$query = $this->db->query($union_query)->get();
$data['data'] = $query->num_rows();
$data['total'] = $query->result_array();

return $data;
```